# svn: Can't open file '/svn/**/db/transactions/59811-1a70.txn/changes': Too many open files(solved)

Tags: file, svn, debian

I had set `ulimit` to **65535** which original is **1024**, and it doesn't work.

```
root@debian:/# ulimit -n
1024
root@debian:/# ulimit -n 65535
root@debian:/# ulimit -n
65535

root@debian:/# svn ci -m 'ck'
Sending        **.txt
Transmitting file data ....svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Can't open file '/svn/**/db/transactions/59811-1a73.txn/changes': Too many open files

root@debian:/svn/**/db/transactions# ls -trl
total 236
drwxr-sr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  6 16:45 59810-1a5i.txn
...
drwxr-sr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  6 20:49 59811-1a73.txn
drwxr-sr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  6 20:50 59811-1a74.txn
```

Solved:

- 1, [update **limits.conf**](https://muhammadtriwibowo.medium.com/set-permanently-ulimit-n-open-files-in-ubuntu-4d61064429a):

```
$ sudo vim /etc/security/limits.conf

# add following lines to it
* soft     nproc          65535    
* hard     nproc          65535   
* soft     nofile         65535   
* hard     nofile         65535
root soft     nproc          65535    
root hard     nproc          65535   
root soft     nofile         65535   
root hard     nofile         65535
```

- 2, `reconnect` to the terminal
- 3, `restart` the svn proccess